# Two modelformset in one view in django

Tags: python, html, django, django-forms, formset

I'm new to django and I'm trying to have two modelformset in one view but I'm getting the 'ManagementForm data is missing or has been tampered with' error. I have already check the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/formsets/#using-more-than-one-formset-in-a-view) and I know that I have to use the management_formset tag and prefix, but I still having the error.

I have looked for the answer and I wasn't able to fix the bug.

With only one formset all is working as espected.

**Views.py**

```
def soil_page(request):
    SoilFormSet = modelformset_factory(model=Soil,exclude=False,min_num=1,extra=0)
    CMCFormSet = modelformset_factory(model=CMC,exclude=False,max_num=1)

    if request.method == "POST":
        formset = SoilFormSet(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None, prefix='soils')
        cmcform = CMCFormSet(request.POST or None,request.FILES or None, prefix='cmcs')

        if formset.is_valid():
            formset.save()

        if cmcform.is_valid():
            cmcform.save()

    else:
        formset = SoilFormSet(prefix='soils')
        cmcform = CMCFormSet(prefix='cmcs')

    return render(request,'soil/soil_form.html',{'formset':formset,
                                                    'cmcform':cmcform,})
```

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <form id="myform" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ formset.management_form }}
    {{ formset.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Save" form='myform'/>
  </form>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <form id="cmcform" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ cmcform.management_form }}
    {{ cmcform.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Save" form='cmcform'/>
  </form>
</div>
```

I hope you can help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found myself an answer for this.

First of all, it seems that for management_form to work it need to be under the same form tag. Something as follow:

```
<div class="container">
  <form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
      {{ formset.management_form }}
      <table>
          {% for form in formset %}
          {{ form }}
          {% endfor %}
      </table>
      <input type="submit" name="soil_button"/>

      {{ cmcformset.management_form }}
      <table>
          {% for form in cmcformset %}
          {{ form }}
          {% endfor %}
      </table>
      <input type="submit" name="cmc_button"/>
  </form>
</div>
```

The problem now is how to use the submit button to only post the desire part of the form. To do that I gave a name to the submit button and specified that the request.POST need to have that name:

```
if formset.is_valid() and 'soil_button' in request.POST:
    formset.save()

if cmcformset.is_valid() and 'cmc_button' in request.POST:
    cmcformset.save()
```

I hope this solution help others.